# How to download a file in onedrive

Tags: c#, download, onedrive

I want to download a file from onedrive using c#.

```
string arquivo = "file.921a7aadee6beb12.921A7AADEE6BEB12!7177";
 string pastaOrigem = "C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Pasta Origem";
 StringBuilder requestDownload = new StringBuilder();
 requestDownload.AppendFormat("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/{0}/content?access token={1}", arquivo, propriedades["access_token"]);
 WebClient myWebClientDownload = new WebClient();
 myWebClientDownload.DownloadFile(requestDownload.ToString(), pastaOrigem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to use the Onedrive REST API.

Full, detailed instructions here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659726.aspx

Comment: I put some good steps to help you in this Question.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43834739/how-to-upload-and-download-file-to-onedrive-for-business-using-c-sharp-applicati/43835418#43835418)