# how to upload and download file to onedrive for business using c# application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

Hi i am new in coding and development. Can somebody please help me to upload and download a file to onedrive for business using c# application?

Comment: Are you sure you want to upload and download the files yourself?  If you want to upload a file you can just put it in your local OneDrive folder and it'll sync it to the cloud for you automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the preferred way is:

- Start using SDK of the Microsoft live SDK (REST API) as in the following link 
  [MSDN OneDrive files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webapps/2014/09/24/upload-and-download-files-from-onedrive)
- and this link also will help you using the 
  [Msdn Code sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659726.aspx)
- You'll use the Commands of Sdk api Put, get, Post, Move and Delete
  LIke this way

  (POST https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
- P.S: Remind you to use multi threading, await, UploadAsync, ... and repeat on cached failures.

Comment: since i am totally new do we have any code handy to run directly?

Comment: from microsoft tutorials for all cases from here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826531.aspx#uploading_files